# Converting bytes to a long: Why do some implementations bitwise-AND each byte with 0xff?

Tags: java, type-conversion, bit-manipulation, byte, long-integer

I'm looking at the implementation of `java.io`'s  `DataInputStream.readLong()` in SE6:

```
private byte readBuffer[] = new byte[8];

public final long readLong() throws IOException {
    readFully(readBuffer, 0, 8);
    return (((long)readBuffer[0] << 56) +
            ((long)(readBuffer[1] & 255) << 48) +
            ((long)(readBuffer[2] & 255) << 40) +
            ((long)(readBuffer[3] & 255) << 32) +
            ((long)(readBuffer[4] & 255) << 24) +
            ((readBuffer[5] & 255) << 16) +
            ((readBuffer[6] & 255) <<  8) +
            ((readBuffer[7] & 255) <<  0));
```

Given that readBuffer[] is an array of **bytes**, why is it necessary to `&` each byte with 255?

When a single byte is cast to a `long`, shouldn't the remaining bits (9-64) bits of the long automatically be set to zero, rendering the `&` unnecessary?

Comment: If you cast a byte with value 0x81 to an int you get a value of 0xFFFFFF81.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

java's byte type is signed, so 0xff (255) == -1, during extending from byte to int/long - signed value is preserved, so if you just have code:

```
final byte a = (byte)0xff;
final long b = a;

System.out.println(b); // output here is -1, not 255
```

so, here comes one trick:

```
final byte a = (byte)0xff;
final long b = a & 0xff; // binary and between byte A and int 0xff

System.out.println(b); // output here is 255
```

so, first byte variable a is promoted to int (and became 0xffffffff) because of sign extension, then we truncate it by doing bitwise AND

Comment: This answer is well expanded and clear. Specially considering being Java is a unsigned-hating language... I'll never understand why Java abolishes unsigned.

Comment: Thank you!  I had been interpreting "byte" as "series of raw bits" -- it hadn't occurred to me it might be "(signed) 8-bit number".

Answer (score -1):

To prevent sign-extension of bytes with negative values.

Comment: I downvoted it because it's a pretty bad answer. It's right, but there's no examples and someone new to binary who saw your answer wouldn't understand it. It's kind of like a code-only answer

Comment: @Jojodmo I would have understood it any time in the last 44 years. Your mileage may vary. It is nothing whatsoever like a code-only answer.